# Why does from flask.cli import main fail when I set FLASK_ENV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv

I have installed flask in a virtual environment as described here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/installation/#install-create-env

- Create a directory and run python3 -m venv venv inside the directory to use virtual environment
- Then source venv/bin/activate to activate the environment
- Then pip install flask

Then I created a script like described here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Then I added export FLASK_APP=hello.py and ran python3 -m flask run which worked just fine

```
python3 -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app "hello.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

But when I then change FLASK_ENV=development and run the same command I get an error

```
python3 -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app "hello.py" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7: No module named flask
```

I unset the FLASK_ENV and ran the same command again and everything works as when I did this the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one solution might be to not set any environment variables and run Flask with just python.

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and then you just activate the virtual environment by `source env/bin/activate` and then run `python main.py`.

You can also set the flask environment in your code by doing `app.config['FLASK_ENV'] = 'development'` but I wouldn't recommend it since if you're going to deploy your Flask app to platforms like Heroku or GCP, it's not going to work as intended.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't give me the auto reload functionality that I am looking for during development

Comment: Try setting `app.debug = True`, see if that works. And remove the `debug=True` from the run call.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be for you to set your environment variables in a `.flaskenv` file in the root directory:

```py
$ touch .flaskenv
```

Then define your environment variables in `.flaskenv`:

```py
FLASK_APP=main.py
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=True
```

Install `python-dotenv` to help with loading your environment variables:

```py
$ pip3 install python-dotenv
```

On your terminal, run:

```py
$ flask run
```

Auto reload should work every time you make a change to your application.